# Should “stand” be replaced by “get” in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Here’s the sentence:

> Stand a chance to win an iPhone X by (doing something).

I think **stand** *a chance* here is overused.

Answer (score 2):

Actually in your example "***stand***" has more the meaning of

> **has**
>
> **Have** a chance to win an iPhone X

"***Get***" would have a similar meaning of *obtaining* a chance, but "***have***" is more often used.

Comment: I thought it should be "*You* stand a chance to win an iPhone X by (doing something)."